# Access LIMIT value as column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This may be easily found elsewhere but I haven't been able to find it yet. I'm just wondering if its possible to access the value being used by the LIMIT clause as a column. I have a ranking algorithm which properly ranks the entities, but I'd like to be able to fetch their numerical rank in the same step.

So in essence, if I have LIMIT 100,5, is there any way to select a column that would then hold 101, 102, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable

```
select *, @rank := @rank + 1
from your_table, (select @rank := 100) r
limit 100, 5
```

Comment: Wow. Glad I asked. I wouldn't have figured that one out on my own. Thanks for that :)